# Origins of the "array like" strings in BASIC

Tags: history, basic

A number of early microcomputer BASICs had 'array like strings' that were unlike MS's system and instead behaved like arrays of char. Substrings were accessed using a syntax like:

```
A$ = B$(1,5)
```

as opposed to the MS style:

```
A$ = LEFT$(B$,4)
```

Note the potential off-by-one.

I know that some minicomputer BASICs also worked this way, I believe HP and Nova were the canonical examples. North Star BASIC also used this style, and I suspect, due to its origins, that Cromenco Extended BASIC did as well.

So the question: does anyone know the first *microcomputer* BASIC that used this style of string notation? And wider, where this style originated?

Comment: Why and how are you distinguishing micros from minis? A given BASIC could be made to run on either.

Comment: HT2000 Basic worked as described; any microcomputer BASICs probably derived such behavior from the HP.

Comment: For reference, both approaches seem to be revisionist treatments :-).  BASIC comes from Dartmouth.  4th edition BASIC had [the CHANGE statement](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dartmouth/BASIC_4th_Edition_Jan68.pdf) to convert between a string variable and an array of ASCII character-codes..

Comment: I do however think I used the LEFT$/RIGHT$ syntax around 1971, dialed in to the UK Open University computer system (I had a maths teacher doing an OU degree in computer science), which I think was running on some HP mini.

Comment: @another-dave I don’t know much about minis, but `LEFT$` seems to have appeared on micros early on; 8K Altair BASIC had it in 1975.

Comment: DEC 1972 basic manual from http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dec/pdp11/rsts/V04/DEC-11-ORBPA-A-D_BASIC-PLUS_LangMan_Oct72.pdf shows that it has BOTH change & left$,right$,mid$ (page 5-13)

Comment: Well DEC was the canonical basis for MS, and it was copied largely from Dartmouth. So we know Dartmouth introduced the MS-style, but that's the opposite question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the earliest BASIC dialects on micros to use these constructs for strings were [North Star BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Star_BASIC) and [Apple Integer BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_BASIC) in 1977, both presumably influenced by HP BASIC. The Apple lineage isn’t surprising since Steve Wozniak worked at HP.

The origin of this approach to substring addressing could be FORTRAN, which uses [a syntax of the form `A(I:L)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6s/index.html).

Comment: Apple BASIC used this style? I didn't know that!

Comment: Only Apple integer basic, Applesoft was standard MS Left/Right/Mid

Comment: Cromenco also did, but that's 1978. So its looking like NS BASIC might be it. What about the Tiny derivatives, did any of them have strings?

Comment: @Maury Tiny BASIC had string literals for `PRINT`; MINOL added a way to store strings and retrieve them, using pointers only (no string variables), but didn’t support sub-strings. I don’t know of any other Tiny derivative which had string variables with something like `A$(2,4)` before NS BASIC.

Answer (score 5):

Sinclair's Basic used the slicing syntax for string manipulation. It even uses it as lvalue. It is imho very clever as it allows some operations without generating lot of garbage as the Microsoft way does. For example: replacing 2 character in the middle of a string

Sinclair syntax:

```
 LET A$="123456789"
 LET A$(4 TO 5)="ab"
 PRINT A$

 123ab6789
```

Microsoft syntax:

```
 A$="123456789"
 A$=LEFT$(A$,4)+"ab"+MID$(A$,6): REM Only if Basic support 2 parameters MID$
 ?A$

 1234ab789   (but internally 4 temporaries were created "123456789","1234","ab" and "789".
```

(MS example might be off by 1)

Comment: At least in the 48k BASIC, string slicing involves the `TO` keyword. It's something like `A$(10 TO 20)`. But I can't remember exactly. It's been a while.

Comment: @OmarL - just tried it and your memory of the syntax is correct, at least for the Spectrum version. (Have edited the example given to be correct as just verified)

Comment: Thank you guys. It was my bad. Too much programming in D and I discovered the sinclair basic slicing only recently.

Comment: Yep, the ZX BASIC string slicing was much better than the LEFT$/RIGHT$/MID$ burden in other BASICs, including the otherwise-elegant BBC BASIC. a$(TO 5) is the left 5 characters, a$(7 TO) is the everything from the 7th character onwards. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: following the leads above, and having burrowed into the rabbit hole much deeper than intended, I think it's safe to say the ultimate answer is [Integer BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_BASIC).

Woz's dialect is (of course) well documented and directly states it was ported from HP. It dates to early 1976, when he started visiting the Homebrew meetings to demonstrate it. I suppose one could mark its "official" release to July 1976 when the Apple I was first put on sale.

The other early possibility is SCELBAL, which was first detailed in February 1976 and shipped in book form a few months later. However, this initial version did not include string support, and the Strings Supplement which added that code is copyrighted to 1977. I strongly suspect it took it string functions from Integer, not HP directly, although I will check with the author on that one.

Comment: Then again, the restriction to 'micro' is an arbitrary when it comes to High Level Languages. After all, they are meant to not be (as) hardware dependent. (Say, were to put an Olivetti P6060?)

Comment: But fails the main razor for the post:  P6060 BASIC does not appear to use slicing and is based on Dartmouth's CONVERT.

Comment: For what's it worth, P6060 BASIC used `EXT$` (extract from-to) and `REP$` (replace), and no `CHANGE` command. So it's a third variant. P6060 BASIC had the `MAT` operations and other Dartmouth features, though.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz The P6060 wasn't mentioned for that feature, but to prove the micro argument. After all, micro has been used rather loosely before the 1980s - which is were you're question takes place, isn't it?